# Assigning ViewBag property in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, getjson

I am trying to assign a JS variable to a ViewBag property and use that property in an Html ActionLink.

However, I'm getting a design time compile error: "Syntax error" right below the getJSON method as `@ViewBag.CustomerID = data.CustomerID;`

Can someone help me out with how this is done?

Here is my code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click to edit Customer", "EditCust", "Customer", new { ViewBag.CustomerID }, null);

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function ()
        {
            var selID = null
            $("#Name").change(function ()
            {
                selID = $("#Name option:selected").val();

                var url = '/Project/SpecificCustomer';
                var param = { Id: selID };
                $.getJSON(url, param, function (data)
                {
                    @ViewBag.CustomerID = data.CustomerID;
                    var html = "<table border='1' cellpadding='3'>";
                    html += "<tr>";
                    html += "<td>" + "Customer ID: " + data.CustomerID + "</td>";
                    html += "</tr>";
                    html += "<tr>";
                    html += "<td>" + "Email: " + data.Email + "</td>";
                    html += "</tr>";
                    html += "<tr>";
                    var FirstName = data.FirstName;
                    FirstName == null ? "" : FirstName;
                    var LastName = data.LastName;
                    LastName == null ? "" : LastName;
                    html += "<td>" + "Name: " + FirstName + " " + LastName + "</td>";
                    html += "</tr>";
                    html += "<tr>";
                    var date1 = new Date(parseInt(data.CreatedDate.substr(6)));
                    date1 == null ? "" : date1;
                    html += "<td>" + "Created: " + date1 + "</td>";
                    html += "</tr>";
                    html += "<tr>";
                    var date2 = new Date(parseInt(data.UpdatedDate.substr(6)));
                    date2 == null ? "" : date2;
                    html += "<td>" + "Updated: " + date2 + "</td>";
                    html += "</tr>";
                    html += "</table>";
                    $("#divData").html('');
                    $("#divData").append(html);
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: By the time the JavaScript runs, the server-side code (such as `ViewBag`) has already finished.  The two don't mix with one another.  Server-side and client-side code runs on completely different machines at completely different times.  Why do you need this value in the `ViewBag` at all?  After the view has rendered, `ViewBag` falls out of scope.  If you need to manipulate something client-side with this value, do it in JavaScript code.  If you need the server to know this value, either set it (in JavaScript) to a form element for posting to the server, or post it with AJAX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This won't work. ViewBag works on server side and it will be out of scope when you get the response of an AJAX request. You should use JavaScript to update the values in your view once you get the response.

You also get the error because an assignment should be in a code block:

```
@{ ViewBag.CustomerID = data.CustomerID; }
```

However this still won't work because data is a JavaScript variable.