# Passing a javascript function's parameter to a ViewBag as index of a list

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, viewbag

Here's my problem :

```
<script>
    function getWSId(clicked_id){
        
        document.getElementById('Edit').value = @(ViewBag.PAAF[clicked_id].Id);
        
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that i cannot use the `clicked_id` inside my ViewBag, it shows this error :

```
error CS0103: The name 'clicked_id' does not exist in the current context
```

How can i pass the value of my JS parameter into my ViewBag please ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assigning ViewBag property in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947298/assigning-viewbag-property-in-javascript)

Comment: This is impossible because they are not in the same life cycle, one on the server side and one on the client side.

Comment: Isn't there any solution to achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C#:

```
ViewBag.Key="YourData";
```

Js :

```
<script>
function getWSId(clicked_id){        
document.getElementById('Edit').value = @(ViewBag.key);       
}
</script>
```

Note : if You  Bind A Model To ViewBag , Need Cast ViewBag To You Model

For Example :

C# :

```
ViewBag.Persons=_db.People.ToList();
```

View Side :

```
@{
var persons=(List<Person>)ViewBag.Persons;
}
```